# How to get and deserialize value created with RedisOutputCacheProvider?

Tags: c#, stackexchange.redis

I'm using Microsoft.Web.Redis.RedisOutputCacheProvider for output caching in Redis. The task is to retrieve manually value from the Redis database and deserialize value for further processing the original HTML.

I tried StackExchange.Redis.IDatabase - can get value by key with StringGet() method, but the problem is that it's serialized. Any thoughts regarding above ?

Answer (score 0):

That's because RedisOutputCacheProvider by default, serializes in a binary format provided by the [BinaryFormatter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.formatters.binary.binaryformatter(v=vs.110).aspx) class.

So you need to deserialize it in the same way OR use a custom serialization method on `RedisOutputCacheProvider`.

Check its [configuration wiki](https://github.com/Azure/aspnet-redis-providers/wiki/Configuration#redisserializertype-string) with the instructions to use a custom serializer.